# How do I change a value in a column based on another value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data mining project using Python. im using this Heart Failure dataset, so my project is about health. i want to create a decision tree id3 from this dataset, and i want it to make it simple and easy to read so i decided to categorize every continuous data, for example i categorized blood pressure level from normal, elevated, hypertension 1, hypertension 2 based on a paper or a legitimate website i read.

i want to categorize Maximum Heart Rate variable, but based on what i read, the low, normal, and high level of Maximum Heart Rate is based on each individuals age. the equation of normal Maximum Heart Rate is 220 - age. so if i know the normal Maximum Heart Rate, i can just straight up decide below normal is low and above normal is high.

so, what im trying to achieve here is :

1. i want to get each records normal Maximum Heart Rate by doing the equation 220 - age.
2. from the equation above, i want to compare it with the individuals actual Maximum Heart Rate record to decide wether they have low, normal or high Maximum Heart Rate.
3. i want to replace each individuals maximum Heart Rate variable with low, normal, or high based from the comparison.

I will give an example below:

[image: age and maximum heart rate]

for example based on the picture above:
the first record age is 40, and Max heart rate is 172. so, 220-40 = 180 is the normal heart rate. and then i compare it to the original record, 172 < 180 it means that the first record have low maximum heart rate. and finally i replace the actual record of MaxHR from 172 to 'low'

i came up with this code but it replace **ALL** MaxHR values with low, and then i asked some friends, they just simply dont know how..

```
df.loc[(df['Age'] - 220) <= df['MaxHR'] , 'MaxHR'] = low
```

Answer (score 0):

Do: `220-df['Age']`

```py
df.loc[(220 - df['Age']) <= df['MaxHR'] , 'MaxHR'] = low
```

Comment: i tried it, it works but only some are affected, not every supposed to be low are changed to low for some reason

Comment: hmmm, that's weird. how far are they from the expected results?